# Compile using Gulp handlebars partials to single HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, handlebars.js

I would like to create a gulpfile to compile from partials into a single HTML file. This is my file structure:

```
| css/
| - main.css
| gulpfile.js
| less/
| - main.less
| index.html
| templates/
| - index.handlebars
| - partials /
| -- header.hbs
| -- footer.hbs
```

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var hbsAll = require('gulp-handlebars-all');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var gulpHandlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars')(handlebars); //default to require('handlebars') if not provided 
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var less = require('gulp-less-sourcemap');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');


handlebars.registerPartial('header', '{{header}}'),
handlebars.registerPartial('footer', '{{footer}}')


gulp.task('default', function () {

    options = {
        partialsDirectory : ['./templates/partials']
    }

    return gulp.src('templates/index.handlebars')
        .pipe(gulpHandlebars( options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

gulp.task('hbsToHTML', function() {
   gulp.src('templates/*.hbs')
  .pipe(hbsAll('html', {
    context: {foo: 'bar'},

    partials: ['templates/partials/*.hbs'],

  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('templates'));
});

gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src('./less/*.less')
    .pipe(less({
        sourceMap: {
            sourceMapRootpath: '../less' // Optional absolute or relative path to your LESS files
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('prefix', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/main.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['hbsToHTML', 'less', 'prefix']);
```

and my index.handlebars file looks like this:

```
{{> header}}
<p>Hello </p>
<p>there </p>
{{> footer}}
```

So, everthing else looks fine, but I can't get the hbsToHTML function to work. Any help is welcome! I know there could be more than a few bugs :(

Answer (score 6):

There's an excellent gulp plugin which does exactly this. You can find it on npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compile-handlebars

Set the path to your partials using the `batch` option. 
Set the path to your templates using `gulp.src`
and set the destination using `gulp.dest`

The example code on the npm page demonstrates this, though in your case you will not need the `partials` option and you may want to set the `ignorePartials` to false so that it picks up all the files you have in your partials directory

Comment: I kinda found an answer, but your way could also be implemented. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out btw and uploaded it to git. Check it.
https://github.com/nikdelig/hbsToHTML

```
       gulp.task('hbsToHTML', function() {
       gulp.src('templates/*.hbs')
      .pipe(hbsAll('html', {
       context: {foo: 'bar'},

     partials: ['templates/partials/**/*.hbs'],}))
      .pipe(rename('index.html'))
      .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
     });
```